# Would the "AOA Disagree" light be the only way 737 MAX pilots could detect malfunctioning AoA sensors?

Tags: boeing-737

Or would there be other warnings on the PFDs?

Comment: If you're referring to such [news about the warning light being an option](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/03/boeing-sold-safety-feature-that-could-have-prevented-737-max-crashes-as-an-option/), then it's too soon to know (under investigation).

Comment: I'm not sure how this is "under investigation".  All you need to answer this question is enough experience with the 737 MAX to explain how AOA sensor values and failures are annunciated. Sure, the specifics of the crashed plane aren't easily available yet, but the OP is asking about AOA mechanics in normal conditions.  We have many other questions about 737 Max AOA that are not being closed.

Comment: @CodyP: Allow me to explain, but if I fail or if we disagree, then perhaps it's best to discuss it in chat/meta or wait and see the VTC outcome. The question lacks context, I provided context in the comment, preceded by an "if", i.e., ideally OP would clarify why they're asking. As it is right now, and given the recent news I linked, there's not much to the question. Accident reports on the other hand would show any shortcomings: in training, training material, certification, what options the pilots had, what options they *realistically* had, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If there was an AOA gauge, then looking at that could have told him there was a problem without an AOA disagree light.

It'd be better than the AOA disagree light too. If the same mechanic maintained both AOA probes or their signals were sent through the same wire harness bundle, they could both agree on the wrong answer.

Comment: Is "if there was" a speculation, or an authoritative confirmation of a lack of an AoA read-out on the Max? The 737NG for example has [AoA read-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkOSJ.png) as an option, but it shows the ADIRU's value, not separate vane values.

Comment: According to national news sources, neither of the two MAX had the AOA gauge (indicator) or the disagree light. See the link in the original post. If the indicator were to show the same signal that the MCAS was using, that'd be the information needed to know systems depending on AOA were going to be weird. Odd that both aircraft had AOA indicator issues, I flew thousands of hours and were around tons of A/C with AOA sensors, and never knew of a failure of one. To have two like this in a short timespan...